# Removing empty XML doc comments

Tags: c#, refactoring, comments, resharper

I have inherited a C# project with countless XML doc comments like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="id"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
```

There's no value to these; they're just a bunch of noise.

Short of writing a custom program, is there a way to eliminate such empty XML comments from my entire solution?  I would like to keep ones that are not empty.  I marked this ReSharper because it seems like it would be the tool to use, but if there's a way that doesn't involve R# that's fine too.

Comment: You could probably construct a Regex to replace all with nothing.

Comment: @dav_i A regex that can handle spacing/line break differences and can distinguish between empty XML and non-empty?  Seems like a pretty tall order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following Regex matches the following:

```
/// <summary></summary>
/// <param name="id"></param>
/// <returns></returns>

/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>

/// <summary>
/// </summary>
/// <param name="id"></param>
```

But not

```
/// <summary>
///  A summary
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Some things</returns>
```

As desired.

```
///\s*<summary>\s*(\r\n///\s*)*(\r\n///)?\s*</summary>\s*\r\n(///.*></.*(\r\n)?)*
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work in Visual Studio's Find and Replace dialog!

It does work in Notepad++ though so you could use that.

Working regex from comment by emodendroket:

```
 *///\s*<summary>\r\n\s*///\s*\r\n\s*///\s*</summary>(\s*(\r\n)*\s*///\s*<[^>]+><‌​/[^>]+>)*
```

Comment: This works in VS:  ` *///\s*<summary>\r\n\s*///\s*\r\n\s*///\s*</summary>(\s*(\r\n)*\s*///\s*<[^>]+></[^>]+>)*`.  Not sure why the backtick for code highlighting won't work.

Comment: Since your idea did ultimately work, despite my skepticism, I'll accept this as the correct answer if you edit in my working regex.